# Consulta sum php

Tags: php, mysql, web

espero me puedan ayudar con esto, estoy creando una web simple que solo hace consultas a una base de datos mysql donde se guardan ventas diarias de distintas sucursales, la info de guarda en una tabla llamada ventas, de la cual uso los siguientes campos: fecha, sucursal y efectivo.

Esta tabla la uno usando un inner join hacia la tabla sucursales, las uno mediante el campo sucursal y de esa forma muestro la descripcion (nombre) de la sucursal.

A esta data la llamo mediante un while dentro de mi tabla, y en efecto, me muestra la sucursal, ademas cree un while para que me cuente los dias (1-31, 1-28, 1-30).

El detalle esta al momento de llamar a las ventas, por algun motivo solo me muestra las ventas del dia 1 de cualquier mes que elija, para que en la siguiente columna me muestre los datos tengo que poner un where en otro query y crear otra columna, segun tengo entendido en programacion no se debe de hacer asi por temas de ahorrar lineas de codigo.

Buscando en esta misma pagina hace años hicieron la misma pregunta pero en su pregunta ya no le pedian las ventas diarias, sino solo las del total del mes, estuve pensando en varias formas de hacerlo, pero no se me ocurre mucho, tengan en cuenta que soy nuevo en esto de programacion, adjunto una imagen para que me entiendan que parte me falta, gracias de antemano y saludos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen de aqui es el codigo que mencione que me genera los datos de cada sucursal y las va agregando a la tabla

Aqui agrego otra imagen donde se puede ver hasta donde llego, tengo las datos de los dias, datos de cada sucursal pero siempre me llama los montos del primer dia, en este caso, agregue otra columna para que se pueda apreciar, la consulta es la que agregue anteriormente, bastante simple pero me es util, es probable que este llamando mal la data o el query este mal enfocado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado otra imagen de como llamo a la data para que ingrese a la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: aunque le ponga un between o delimitadores a la fecha tales como >= o <=, siempre muestra la primera fecha, agrego eso porque en la captura no puse eso y se puede pensar que no lo estoy poniendo y por eso falla

PD2: la ultima imagen muestra lo que pude conseguir pero mediante cases, indicando dia 1, dia 2, etc. considero que escribir cada case de esa forma no es lo correcto en programacion, en su lugar tengo la idea de que se puede hacer mediante un for que recorra cada dia de la semana y de esa forma se haga una consulta con esa misma variable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pásanos tu base de datos con phpmyadmin, exportar y la consulta que has intentado, todo en SQL para que podamos ayudarte :)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @DavidJP subi las tablas a wetransfer, https://we.tl/t-4FlK5DTl0O aqui esta el enlace, gracias por tu interes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que estás buscando, para octubre de 2022, sería algo así:

```
SELECT Local,c2.*,Total_mensual
  FROM (
    SELECT Cod_Alm,
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=1,Efectivo,0)) '1',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=2,Efectivo,0)) '2',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=3,Efectivo,0)) '3',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=4,Efectivo,0)) '4',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=5,Efectivo,0)) '5',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=6,Efectivo,0)) '6',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=7,Efectivo,0)) '7',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=8,Efectivo,0)) '8',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=9,Efectivo,0)) '9',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=10,Efectivo,0)) '10',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=11,Efectivo,0)) '11',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=12,Efectivo,0)) '12',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=13,Efectivo,0)) '13',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=14,Efectivo,0)) '14',
      SUM(IF(DAY(Fecha)=15,Efectivo,0)) '15'
      FROM (
        SELECT Cod_Alm,DATE(Fecha) Fecha,
          SUM(Efectivo) Efectivo
          FROM t_venta
          GROUP BY 1,2  
      ) c1
      WHERE YEAR(Fecha)=2022
      AND MONTH(Fecha)=10
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT Cod_Alm,SUM(Efectivo) Total_mensual
      FROM t_venta
      WHERE YEAR(Fecha)=2022
      AND MONTH(Fecha)=10
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c3 USING(Cod_Alm)
  LEFT JOIN t_config USING(Cod_Alm);
```

Con la que obtendrías:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------+
| Local      | Cod_Alm | 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5        | 6       | 7       | 8    | 9    | 10   | 11   | 12   | 13   | 14   | 15   | Total_mensual |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------+
| BAL 13     | 00018   | 2914.00 |  766.70 | 1575.90 | 1200.30 |   858.60 | 2422.60 | 1009.80 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |      10747.90 |
| NULL       | 00031   | 3133.80 |  431.50 | 1024.40 | 1009.10 |  1767.20 |  690.00 |  854.40 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       8910.40 |
| NULL       | 00032   | 1602.00 |  742.40 |  902.20 |  368.50 |   561.90 | 1597.70 |  613.70 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6388.40 |
| GAMARRA 7  | 00036   | 1716.00 |  228.90 | 1126.80 |  682.00 |   496.80 |  727.40 | 1430.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6408.20 |
| NULL       | 00039   |  935.50 |  521.00 |  591.50 |  722.00 |   136.00 |  534.50 |  463.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       3903.50 |
| ALTA 7     | 00040   | 1746.30 |  415.50 |  902.00 |  812.80 |   934.50 | 1274.90 |  669.10 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6755.10 |
| SUL 6      | 00048   | 4505.30 | 1647.50 | 1486.40 | 1678.60 |  2491.30 | 1911.40 | 1357.70 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |      15078.20 |
| PIU        | 00049   | 2354.60 |  920.80 |  413.80 |  321.00 |   778.70 | 1438.70 |  264.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6491.60 |
| CAJ 8      | 00051   | 1379.00 | 1915.50 |  664.50 |  310.00 |   701.90 |  773.90 |  510.90 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6255.70 |
| TINGO      | 00052   | 1074.00 |  718.00 |  381.50 |  997.00 |   853.00 |  222.00 |  511.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       4756.50 |
| Meza 1     | 00054   |  429.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  201.00 |    32.00 |  236.00 |  832.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       1730.00 |
| BAL 98     | 00057   | 2877.60 |  398.90 | 1062.60 | 1782.90 |  1746.80 | 1987.00 | 1340.50 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |      11196.30 |
| PIZA 5     | 00060   | 1230.50 |  175.80 |  519.60 |  948.90 |   136.80 |  817.20 |  986.60 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       4815.40 |
| PROC       | 00064   |  886.60 |  164.80 |  575.90 |  362.40 |   488.60 |  336.70 |  337.50 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       3152.50 |
| PLAZA      | 00065   |  702.40 |  369.30 |  239.10 |  371.80 |   407.80 |  802.70 |   78.90 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       2972.00 |
| PUCALLPA 2 | 00066   |  426.30 |  222.40 |  352.80 |  529.30 |   467.80 |  547.50 |  372.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       2918.40 |
| PUC        | 00066   |  426.30 |  222.40 |  352.80 |  529.30 |   467.80 |  547.50 |  372.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       2918.40 |
| NULL       | 00067   |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |     0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |          0.00 |
| NULL       | 00068   |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |   20.00 |   205.60 |    0.00 |   80.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |        305.60 |
| NULL       | 00069   |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    40.60 |    0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |         40.60 |
| NULL       | 00070   |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |     0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |          0.00 |
| NULL       | 00072   | 1462.00 |  669.10 |  782.00 |  886.00 |   536.50 |  521.00 |  510.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       5366.60 |
| CHIMU      | 00073   |  749.80 |  858.70 |  473.10 | 1476.60 |   827.50 |  818.00 |  338.80 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       5542.50 |
| ABA 7      | 00074   | 1041.60 |  176.70 |  383.30 |  704.80 |   487.40 |  481.60 |  283.20 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       3558.60 |
| MINKA      | 00075   |  915.00 |  392.10 |  420.10 |  700.00 |   217.30 |  520.60 |   48.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       3213.40 |
| NULL       | 01001   | 6611.80 |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 |     0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |       6611.80 |
| NULL       | 01002   |  848.17 |    0.00 | 2671.90 | 2078.59 | 25536.04 |    0.00 |    0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |      31134.70 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------------+
```

Para los datos de muestra que has facilitado:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_venta` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cod_Alm` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Efectivo` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tarjeta` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NotaCredito` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gasto` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Cod_Alm` (`Cod_Alm`),
  KEY `Fecha` (`Fecha`)
);
CREATE TABLE `t_config` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cod_Alm` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Local` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Server` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bd` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pas` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ubi` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Cod_Alm` (`Cod_Alm`)
);
```

Ten en cuenta que únicamente he pivotado la tabla para los primeros 15 días del mes, para los demás es análogo, y que la consulta únicamente muestra octubre, para otros meses tendrás que modificarla.

Fíjate en que ha sido construida en varios pasos: `c1`, `c2`, `c3` y varios `JOIN` finales. De hecho hay locales que, como no tienes registrados, aparecen como `NULL`.

Espero que te resulte útil, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para mejorar la respuesta en función de lo que necesites saber.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, esa solucion tambien la llegue a encontrar.
Buscando en internet encontre que mediante case puedo lograr que me muestre los datos siempre que exista la data, pero en este caso, en un mes existen 30 dias promedio, mi idea inicial se enfoca mas en saber como podria plantear la consulta en php, es decir, indicar un variable y que recorra esa variable durante los dias del mes elegido

Comment: Agregue una imagen para que se pueda ver lo que consegui antes, si bien es cierto consegui mostrar lo que queria, hacer cada case es engorroso y no es una buena practica o eso me dijeron algunos compañeros que tambien programan

Comment: En PHP es mucho más sencillo pivotar la tabla a partir de `c1` con un simple bucle `for` que vaya haciendo los `fetch()` cuando sean necesarios. Para que te diga cómo hacerlo, antes debes intentar algo previamente y nunca, nunca, poner código como imagen.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar encontrarlo y sobre lo del codigo como imagen no lo sabia, lo tendre en cuenta en mis siguientes preguntas

Comment: Soy yo de nuevo, pude hacer que recorra todo el mes en php al momento de llamar la data en mi tabla, eso es un avance, tengo otra consulta, existe la forma de cambiar los 0.0 por el simbolo de - (menos)? se me ocurrio usar case y si muestra el ( - ) donde hay 0.00 pero no se si sea buena idea modificar el codigo que pusiste que dicho sea de paso me ayudo muchisimo! que riesgo puede ocurrir de usar solo cases?

Comment: Tanto el `case` cómo PHP son igual de eficientes, hazlo en el lenguaje que te resulte más cómodo, o en ambos, para practicar. No hay ningún riesgo. Para el cambio de signo plantea una nueva pregunta y pon un ejemplo concreto para que podamos ayudarte :)